# Extracting Electric Dipole Moment from Matrix Element via Form Factor

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, beyond-the-standard-model

The quark matrix element of the electromagnetic current $J^{em}$ can be written as :

$\left<\bar{u}(p')|J^{em}|u(p)\right> = \bar{u}(p')\Gamma_{\mu}u(p)$

Now this $\Gamma_{\mu}$ is as follows:

$ \Gamma_{\mu} = F_{1}(q^{2})\gamma_{\mu} + iF_{2}(q^{2})\sigma_{\mu\nu}q^{\nu}  - F_{3}(q^2)\gamma_{5}\sigma_{\mu\nu}q^{\nu} + F_{A}(q^{2})\left( \gamma_{\mu}q^{2} - 2m_{q}q_{\mu}\right)\gamma_{5}$

where $F_{1}(q^2)$, $F_{2}(q^2)$, $F_{3}(q^2)$ and $F_{A}(q^2)$ are form factors which when evaluated at zero momentum transfer i.e. $ q^{2} = 0 $ give electric charge, anomalous magnetic dipole moment, **electric dipole moment** and anapole moment respectively.

My aim is to **evaluate the electric dipole moment i.e. evaluate $F_{3}(0)$**. How do I extract this quantity $F_{3}$ from the matrix element? 
I am following the textbook Quantum Field Theory by Peskin and Schroder or Page 160 of the book by Itzykson and Zuber in which they show how to extract the anomalous magnetic moment but not the other form factors.

Of course, the assumption is that I am working with a P and CP violating theory, otherwise $F_{3}=0$ due to P invariance.

Comment: You are asking the wrong question here. Electromagnetic part of the interaction does not violate parity and hence you won't get a electric dipole moment form factor as it is automatically zero. You need to have an interaction part which  is chiral (at least in higher orders). You can have a electroweak part of the interaction to get a term like that in similar fashion as magnetic dipole moment because $\psi$ would be replaced by $(1-\gamma_5)\psi $.

Comment: As I stated above, I am working in the context of a CP violating theory. So, the EDM in this case doesn't automatically go to zero.

Comment: My point was that as long as you are considering matrix element of $J^{em}$, you won't get an EDM part as electromagnetic interactions conserve parity.

Comment: Thank you but I understand that; maybe I should have been clearer in the way I framed my question. I am concerned with calculating the EDM of a fermion in a renormalizable theory which has scalar and pseudoscalar couplings i.e. a source of CP violation. So, basically, the loop diagram I am concerned with has a mediating particle in the loop with a photon and two external fermion lines (the usual EDM triangle graph). Now, the 1-loop calculation is trivial but how do I extract the EDM from my calculation is what I am actually after. Any comments about this would be extremely helpful.

Comment: I am not sure why it should be a problem to extract electric part if you can extract the magnetic part. You are basically looking for $\gamma_{5}\gamma_{ab}$ term which due to duality relation is same as $2i\epsilon_{abcd}\gamma^{cd}$ and the epsilon term basically converts magnetic to electric part as $^*F_{ab}=\epsilon_{abcd}F^{cd}$. After that you need two fermionic vertices to extract $\gamma_{ab}$ term as $\gamma_{ab}=\gamma_{a}\gamma_{b}-\eta_{ab}$ holds.